# Placing MVC Content folder into Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

First of all, I do understand, that MVC 3 default template's `Content` folder is not a mandatory css/img/etc. store folder.

I still like the concept of `Content` folder to be a "reference-able" storage location for images and style sheets and other possible stuff (I also place entire jQuery custom controls into `Content`'s sub folders with .js files in them).

I haven't used MVC `Area`s thus far in my projects, since I didn't have a complex enough one's. Now it's time.

And I am thinking about placing a separate `Content` folder in each `Area`. Will it work? Is there something "bad" that can turn out of it? Like me not being able to reference resources in it via `../Content/MyControl`? Or is MVC `Area` just like a root of the project, but a separate one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The area is almost just like a separate project (but not really).  You can either use

```
Url.Content("~/Areas/AreaName/Content/FileInfo");
```

or

```
<link type="text/css" src="RootOfSiteInfo/Areas/AreaName/Content/FileInfo"/>
```

There should not be any issues not being able to reach the static content, though personally I leave everything in the root content folder (single point of storage) since many times CSS and the likes are shared in our projects across areas.

Comment: I was only be able to make it work by adding "Areas" to the url. If someone knows how to avoid this I would be appreciated.

Comment: If the physical path from your site root is Areas/AreaName/Content/file.ext, then yes, you would need to include Areas in the path.